# How can I use a while loop to get my image from my database and then echo it?

Tags: php, sql, while-loop, phpmyadmin, echo

I don't think a `header(content-type: image/jpg)` would work in my case. None of my hours of practice or research with php images has shown me how to do this.

```
<?php
$vin = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['VIN']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE VIN = '$vin'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Model FROM inventory WHERE VIN = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $vin);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($model);
$stmt->fetch();
echo "<h1>$model</h1>";


// Loop through all the rows returned by the query, creating a table row for each
while ($result_ar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $img = $result_ar['IMG'];
  $year = $result_ar['YEAR'];
  $make = $result_ar['Make'];
  $model = $result_ar['Model'];
  $trim = $result_ar['TRIM'];
  $color = $result_ar['EXT_COLOR'];
  $interior = $result_ar['INT_COLOR'];
  $mileage = $result_ar['MILEAGE'];
  $transmission = $result_ar['TRANSMISSION'];
  $price = $result_ar['ASKING_PRICE'];
}
```

When I go to echo my `$img` I get weird looking characters that look like this [view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAmW1.jpg). What is the correct syntax to display the image data correctly? Mine wont work.

```
    echo "$img<br>";
    echo "$year $make $model</p>";
    echo "<p>Asking Price: $price </p>";
    echo "<p>Exeterior Color: $color</p>";
    echo "<p>Interior Color: $interior </p>";
```

Comment: In which column type are you saving your image in database?

Comment: <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo $img; ?> " 
     />. Here instead of jpg use sutaible mime type